# .NET - It is possible to use DI with the State Pattern?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, dependency-injection, state-pattern

I'm studying design patterns in .NET and currently i'm trying to implement the State Pattern. But today i got to a problem and i can't figure out how to fix this situation.

I have some state classes, all of them implementing the state interface. One of the last states should connect to a data base, through a service injected by the .NET API Startup class, to persist the data and finish up the process.

The problem is... because of the dependency injection that i need to be in the final state, i can't instanciate this state object to progress to this point. I don't know how to continue from there. I don't know if i'm using the pattern wrong or if the use of dependency injection in this pattern is the problem. I can't give all the details of the problem because my studie's project is a little big mess at this moment, so i made a quick mimic of the structure i'm trying to build in my application.

States interface and the OperatingClass who will execute the state behaviour:

```
    public interface IOperationState
    {
        public int ExecuteOperation(OperatingClass operatingClass);
    }
```

```
    public class OperatingClass
    {
        public IOperationState OperationState { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public double value { get; set; }

        public OperatingClass(int id)  //constructor
        {
            this.id = id;
            value = 0;
            OperationState = new StartingState();
        }

        public int Execute()
        {
            return OperationState.ExecuteOperation(this);
        }
    }
```

Main Service: is the service who my controller calls after receive the API Post Method:

```
    public class MainService
    {
        public int ExecuteFullOperation(int id)
        {
            //Receives an id and execute the state transition till the end;
            var operatingClass = new OperatingClass(id);
            return operatingClass.Execute();
        }
    }
```

The classes who represents the states and do the respective actions:

```
    public class StartingState : IOperationState
    {
        
        public int ExecuteOperation(OperatingClass operatingClass)
        {
            // Do something...
            operatingClass.OperationState = new MiddleState();
            return operatingClass.Execute();
        }
    }
```

```
    public class MiddleState : IOperationState
    {
        public int ExecuteOperation(OperatingClass operatingClass)
        {
            //Do something with the value... let's supose the result is 123, but it does not matter rn;
            operatingClass.value = 123;

            //Here is the problem: FinalState needs the PersistenceService, who
            //receives a injected class to acess the database;
            operatingClass.OperationState = new FinalState();

            //I want to execute it and return the sucess or failure of the persistence.
            return operatingClass.Execute();
        }
    }
```

```
    public class FinalState : IOperationState
    {
        private readonly IPersistenceService PersistenceService;
        public FinalState(IPersistenceService persistenceService)
        {
            PersistenceService = persistenceService;
        }

        public int ExecuteOperation(OperatingClass operatingClass)
        {
            return PersistenceService.PersistData(operatingClass.id, operatingClass.value) ? 200 : 503;
        }
    }
```

Additional info: i made the PersistenceService be injected in the Startup.cs as a Transient (i dont know how to make it in another way at this moment).

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddTransient<IPersistenceService, PersistenceService>();
            // Irrelevant configurations for the question.
            services.AddControllers();
        }
```

Please, help me if you can. I'm having a hard time trying to figure it out by myself.
Thank you for your patience and for your time reading it.

Comment: Which classes (or rather: instances) are you trying to inject where? Maybe I don't fully understand your concept, but I don't see where DI is coming into play here.

Comment: I need to inject PersistenceService into FinalState. PersistenceService is a class who makes contact with the database and have more DI into itself (configuration to read the appsettings connection string, other injections to retry logic and logging, etc). Because of that, PersistenceService needs to be injected into what ever needs to access the database, wich in this case is FinalState class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, we need some simple factory which will supply all necessary dependencies by their type. So let's create types for states:

```
public enum StateType
{
    Start,
    Middle,
    Final
}
```

And simple factory:

```
public class StateFactory
{
    private Dictionary<StateType, IOperationState> _stateByType;


    // you can inject these dependencies through DI like that:
    // public StateFactory(StartingState startingState, 
    //     MiddleState middleState, FinalState finalState, 
    //     PersistenceService persistenceService)
    public StateFactory()
    {
        _stateByType = new Dictionary<StateType, IOperationState>()
        {
            { StateType.Start, new StartingState(this) },
            { StateType.Middle, new MiddleState(this) },
            { StateType.Final, new FinalState(new PersistenceService()) }
        };
    }

    public IOperationState GetByType(StateType stateType) => 
        _stateByType[stateType];
}
```

Then we should register all our dependencies:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<IPersistenceService, PersistenceService>();
    
    services.AddTransient<StartingState>();
    services.AddTransient<MiddleState>();
    services.AddTransient<FinalState>();
    
    services.AddTransient<MainService>();
    services.AddTransient<OperatingClass>();
    services.AddTransient<PersistenceService>();
    services.AddTransient<StateFactory>();

}
```

Our states would look like this:

```
public class StartingState : IOperationState
{
    private StateFactory _factory;

    public StartingState(StateFactory stateFactory)
    {
        _factory = stateFactory;
    }

    public int ExecuteOperation(OperatingClass operatingClass)
    {
        // Do something...
        // operatingClass.OperationState = new MiddleState();
        operatingClass.OperationState = _factory.GetByType(StateType.Middle);
        return operatingClass.Execute();
    }
}
```

And `MiddleState` would look like this:

```
public class MiddleState : IOperationState
{
    private StateFactory _factory;

    public MiddleState(StateFactory stateFactory)
    {
        _factory = stateFactory;
    }

    public int ExecuteOperation(OperatingClass operatingClass)
    {
        //Do something with the value... let's supose the result is 123, 
        // but it does not matter rn;
        operatingClass.value = 123;

        //Here is the problem: FinalState needs the PersistenceService, who
        //receives a injected class to acess the database;
        operatingClass.OperationState = _factory.GetByType(StateType.Final);

        //I want to execute it and return the sucess or failure of the persistence.
        return operatingClass.Execute();
    }
}
```

And `Final state` should look like this:

```
 public class FinalState : IOperationState
{
    private readonly IPersistenceService _persistenceService;

    public FinalState(IPersistenceService persistenceService)
    {
        _persistenceService = persistenceService;
    }

    public int ExecuteOperation(OperatingClass operatingClass)
    {
        return _persistenceService
            .PersistData(operatingClass.id, operatingClass.value) 
                ? 200 
                : 503;
    }
}
```

And other classes sush as OperatingClass would use `StateFactory` too:

public class OperatingClass
{
public IOperationState OperationState { get; set; }
public int id { get; set; }
public double value { get; set; }

```
    public OperatingClass(int id, StateFactory stateFactory)  //constructor
    {
        this.id = id;
        value = 0;
        // OperationState = new StartingState();
        OperationState = stateFactory.GetByType(StateType.Start);
    }

    public int Execute()
    {
        return OperationState.ExecuteOperation(this);
    }
}
```

And it is necessary to create concrete example of `PersistenceService`:

```
public interface IPersistenceService
{
    bool PersistData(int id, double value);
}

public class PersistenceService : IPersistenceService
{
    public bool PersistData(int id, double value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to inject states into StateFactory through DI. But at the same time I want to inject StateFactory into states. How do I avoid circular dependency in this case?

Comment: @user3392683 could you ask a new question? It is a good practice to have one post per one question

Comment: ...Either inject IServiceProvider into the states, or into StateFactory (I know, antipattern...), I can't think of anything better, as usual.
@StepUp

Comment: I'm sorry, just responding to your suggestion
"...you can inject these dependencies through DI as follows: public StateFactory(StartingState startingState..."

New query = loss of context